# Get geopandas geo or affine transform

Tags: geopandas, rasterio, rasterization, affine-transformation

Does anyone know how to get the affine transformation from a geopandas dataframe?

I need this for rasterising geospatial vector data with rasterio.

```
shapes = ((geom,value) for geom, value in zip(geodataframe.geometry, len(geodataframe)*[255]))

numpy_array = features.rasterize(
    shapes,
    out_shape=self.tile_size,
    transform=geodataframe.transform???,
    all_touched=True)
```

I am however still missing the transform part.

Comment: You could use geocube: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/examples.html

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found to work for anybody else searching is to create the transform yourself.

```
import affine
transform = affine.Affine(res, 0, minx, 0, -res, maxy)

shapes = ((geom,value) for geom, value in zip(dataset.geometry, len(dataset)*[val]))

raster = rasterio.features.rasterize(shapes,
                                     out_shape=tile_size,
                                     transform=transform)
```

whereby `res` is the spatial resolution (ie 1pixel = 2m). `minx` and `maxy` correspond to the geographic position and the y axis is chosen negative to match the different coordinate system of the another raster I am using.

Comment: just what I needed